# How to get textbox's value and turning into PDF format with itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm coming with a question, and I wish someone could answer to it.
I can't convert the string value of my textbox to put it in a PDF File Format.
I got an error, something like:

> impossible to convert string to iTextSharp.Text.IElement...

I tried to cast it but it doesn't work.

So, my question, how to do to put my value into my PDF File Format?

Here is a bit of my code:

```
string adresseProf = adProf.Text;
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 20f, 20f, 10f);
doc.Open();
doc.Add(adresseProf); //I tried something like : doc.Add((IElement)adresseProf);
```

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: iTextSharp is EOL, and has been replaced by iText 7. Only security fixes will be added.  https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/tree/master

Comment: This appears to be paid software. Have you tried contacting their support? Getting official documentation from them?

Comment: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/82/itextsharp-adding-text-with-chunks-phrases-and-paragraphs

Comment: Ok, thanks for saying to me it, I didn't know that. I will try to contact them to know what I can do. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iText 5 `Document` class has only one `Add` method,

```
public virtual bool Add(IElement element)
```

and there is no `IElement` operator allowing implicit or explicit casting of a `string` to an `IElement`.

Thus, you cannot simply call `doc.Add(adresseProf)` and expect that to work. What you can do instead, though, is look for an `IElement` implementation that can be used to wrap your `string`.

One candidate is the `Paragraph` class which implements `IElement` and has a constructor taking a single `string` parameter:

```
public Paragraph(string str)
```

So you can write the following in your code

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph(adresseProf));
```